# How to remove elements from list when each character is identical (Python)?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
sample = ['AAAA','ABCB','CCCC','DDEF']
```

I need to eliminate all elements where every character is identical to itself in the element eg. AAAAA,CCCCC

```
output = ['ABCB','DDEF']

sample1 =[]
for i in sample:
    for j in i:
       if j == j+1:    #This needs to be corrected to if all elements in i identical to each other i.e. if all "j's" are the same
        sample1.pop(i)
```

print sample

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 sample = ['AAAA','ABCB','CCCC','DDEF']
 output = [sublist for sublist in sample if len(set(sublist)) > 1]
```

## EDIT to answer comment.

```
sample = [['CGG', 'ATT'], ['ATT', 'CCC']]
output = []
for sublist in sample:
    if all([len(set(each)) > 1 for each in sublist]):
        output.append(sublist)

# List comprehension (doing the same job as the code above)
output2 = [sublist for sublist in sample if 
           all((len(set(each)) > 1 for each in sublist))]
```

Comment: I needed help with an extension to this problem. If I had a list of lists..[['CGG', 'ATT'], ['ATT', 'CCC']], how can I eliminate pairs, where one of the pairs has all identical elements? So here output would be [['CGG', 'ATT']]

Comment: By saying all identical you mean that you want to remove ['ATT', 'CCC'] because there is 'CCC' in it?

Answer (score 2):

```
sample = ['AAAA','ABCB','CCCC','DDEF']

sample1 = []
for i in sample:
    if len(set(i)) > 1:
        sample1.append(i)
```

Comment: I needed help with an extension to this problem. If I had a list of lists..[['CGG', 'ATT'], ['ATT', 'CCC']], how can I eliminate pairs, where one of the pairs has all identical elements (eg. CCC)? So here output would be [['CGG', 'ATT']]